# Unable to declare dynamic integer array in c++, possible c++11 error

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am new to C++ and am facing a problem with declaring dynamic arrays (of type integer) using the correct syntax. This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int* pArray(new int[5]{10,20,30,40,50});
    *(pArray + 1) -= 2; //Subtracting 2 from index 1 of pArray
    cout << *pArray << ", " << *(pArray + 1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And I get this error when I compile and run this code on Atom for Mac (atom.io):

```
/Users/pmn/Desktop/myprogram.cpp:6:27: error: expected ')'
int* pArray(new int[5]{10,20,30,40,50});
                      ^
/Users/pmn/Desktop/myprogram.cpp:6:16: note: to match this '('
int* pArray(new int[5]{10,20,30,40,50});
           ^
1 error generated.
```

I am guessing this has something to do with C++11 syntax maybe? How do I solve this syntax problem? I just want to declare a dynamic integer array of size 5, directly and immediately, without doing this:

```
pArray[0] = 10;
pArray[1] = 20;

// and so on...
```

Just to clarify, I'm using Atom for Mac (atom.io)

Comment: That is because you are using [C++11 list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) in `{10,20,30,40,50}`

Comment: Atom is text editor, not a compiler. You shouldn't blindly trust its error reporting. Especially when a proper compiler accepts your code as is: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cbb2845db8d549e

Comment: Suggestion - if you are not prohibited from using it for whatever reason, consider using [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 0):

As StoryTeller said, Atom is not a compiler. Your code runs fine. Just get a real compiler for c++, MinGW p.e.